# Elements in a list are overwritten

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to program a function which creates the linear span of a list of independent vectors, but it seems that the last calculated vector overwrites all other elements. I'd be nice if someone could help me fixing it.

```
def span_generator(liste,n):
    """function to generate the span of a list of linear independent 
    vectors(in liste) in the n-dimensional vectorspace of a finite 
    field with characteristic 2, returns a list of all elements which 
    lie inside the span"""
    results=[]
    blank=[]
    for i in range(n):
        blank.append(0)
    a=blank
    if len(liste)>1:
        listenwert=liste[-1]
        liste.pop(-1)
        values=span_generator(liste,n)    
        for i in range(2):
            for j in range(len(values)):
                for k in range(n):
                    a[k]=(i*listenwert[k]+values[j][k])%2
                results.append(a)
    else:       
        for i in range(2):
            for j in range(n):
                a[j]=(i*liste[0][j])
            results.append(a)    
    print(results)
    return results
```

`print(span_generator([[1,0],[0,1]],2))` gives following results

```
[[1, 0], [1, 0]]
[[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]]
[[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]]
```

instead of the expected: `[[0,0],[1,0],[0,1],[1,1]]`

Edit: I tried to simplify the program with itertools.product, but it didn't solve the problem.

```
def span_generator(liste):
    n=len(liste[0])
    results=[]
    coeff=list(itertools.product(range(2), repeat=n))
    blank=[]
    for i in range(n):
        blank.append(0)
    for i in range(len(coeff)):
        a=blank
        for j in range(len(coeff[0])):
            for k in range(n):
                a[k]=(a[k]+coeff[i][j]*liste[j][k])%2
        results.append(a)
    return results
```

Output: `span_generator([[0,1],[1,0]])
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]`
But it should give `[[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]`

Another example: `span_generator([[0,1,1],[1,1,0]])` should give `[[0,0,0],[0,1,1],[1,1,0],[1,0,1]]` (2=0 since i'm calculating modulo 2)

Comment: what is the meaning of `n`?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want a span of linear combinations of the beginning vectors with maximum coefficient `n`?

Comment: N gives the number of entries in a vector, Therfore it's actually unecessary to pass it to the function, because it's already given with liste via n=len(liste[0]).

Comment: so for `span_generator([[a, b], [c, d]])` you would want the result to be `[[0, 0], [a, b], [c , d], [a + c, b + d]`]

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: you over complicate your example code. Why do you make a list out of everything instead of using the iterators. They are a lot more elegant, readeable and efficient

Answer (score 1):

## Coefficients

You can use `itertools.product` to generate the coefficients:

```
n = len(liste[0])
coefficients = itertools.product(range(2), repeat=len(liste))
```

yields an iterator with this content:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

## Linear combinations

You can then selectively multiply the results with the `transpose` of your `liste`  (`list(zip(*liste)))`

```
for coeff in coefficients:            
        yield [sum((a * c) for a, c in zip(transpose[i], coeff)) for i in range(n)]
```

which take for each dimensionality (`for i in range(n)`) the sum of the products

```
def span_generator3(liste):
    n = len(liste[0])
    transpose = list(zip(*liste))
    coefficients = itertools.product(range(2), repeat=len(liste))
    for coeff in coefficients:            
        yield [sum((a * c) for a, c in zip(transpose[i], coeff)) % 2 for i in range(n)]
```

this produces an iterator. If you want the result in a list-form, just can `list()` on the iterator

## Result

```
list(span_generator3([[1,2],[4,8]]))
```

output:

```
[[0, 0], [4, 8], [1, 2], [5, 10]]
```

## Higher dimensions

```
list(sorted(span_generator3([[1,2, 4],[8, 16, 32], [64, 128, 256]])))
```

output:

```
[[0, 0, 0],
 [1, 2, 4],
 [8, 16, 32],
 [9, 18, 36],
 [64, 128, 256],
 [65, 130, 260],
 [72, 144, 288],
 [73, 146, 292]]
```

## Modulo 2

If you want the result modulo 2, that's just adding 2 characters in the right place

```
def span_generator3_mod2(liste):
    n = len(liste[0])
    transpose = list(zip(*liste))
    coefficients = itertools.product(range(2), repeat=len(liste))
    # print(list(itertools.product(range(2), repeat=len(liste))))
    for coeff in coefficients:            
        yield [sum((a * c) for a, c in zip(transpose[i], coeff)) % 2 for i in range(n)]
```

`list(span_generator3_mod2([[0,1,1],[1,1,0]]))` gives

```
[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: I copied your code and used your examples, but I got a diffrent output for 'higher dimensions'. But itertools.product should fix my problems. Thank you

Comment: Strange. What's your result then?

Comment: I get     [[0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 4], [2, 4, 8], [8, 16, 32], [9, 18, 36], [10, 20, 40], [16, 32, 64], [17, 34, 68], [18, 36, 72], [64, 128, 256], [65, 130, 260], [66, 132, 264], [72, 144, 288], [73, 146, 292], [74, 148, 296], [80, 160, 320], [81, 162, 324], [82, 164, 328], [128, 256, 512], [129, 258, 516], [130, 260, 520], [136, 272, 544], [137, 274, 548], [138, 276, 552], [144, 288, 576], [145, 290, 580], [146, 292, 584]]  as a result

Comment: Can you add a `print(coefficients)` before the for-loop and share that result?

Comment: `print(coefficients)` gives '<itertools.product object at 0x00000000038C2D80>', `print(list(coefficients))` gives `[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2)]` but it alters the output of `list(sorted(span_generator3([[1,2, 4],[8, 16, 32], [64, 128, 256]])))` to `[]`

Comment: and `list(collections)` exhausts the the iterator.A side-effect I forgot.